# R: ifelse statement for two different scenarios defined by group

Tags: r, if-statement, plot

I have a sample dataframe which I want to plot conditionally (two different plot scenarios, the only difference is the extent definition of the x axis).

```
 xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(47,47,47,47,259,259,259),YEAR=c(1932,1942,1965,1989,2007,2008,2014),VALUE=c(0,NA,-6,-16,0,-9,-28))
```

For this I am trying to iplement an `ifelse()` statement but I can't figure out how I could make this compatible with my two plot loops.

What I am attempting to do is the following: I am generating different plots divided by groups (ID).

```
# split data by index 
   ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID'])
```

If in a group there are `YEAR`s that ONLY lie between 1946 and 2014 Plot Scenario 1 should by executed.

```
# If the values in a group lie ONLY between YEAR 1946 and 2014 and not lower than 1946
    if(xy$YEAR > 1946 & xy$YEAR < 2014) { # <- this needs to be corrected
    ### PLOT Scenario 1 
    for(i in 1:length(ind)){
      png(names(ind[i]), width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
      par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
      plot(x = c(1946, 2014),
           y = range(ind[[i]][,'VALUE']),
           type='b',
           main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],     
        dev.off() 
    }
```

If there are also `YEAR`s under 1946 included in a group, Plot Scenario 2 should be executed.

```
else{
  ### PLOT Scenario 2 (plot with automatic axis range when also YEARs under 1946 are in a group)
  for(i in 1:length(ind)){
    png(names(ind[i]), width=1679, height=1165, res=150)    
    par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
    plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
         type='b',
         main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
    dev.off()  
  }
}
```

How could I specify the `YEAR`s in each group to introduce it in the if statement correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do this in ifelse, you could wrap your loops in functions, then call them...

So you would say

```
 ifFunction<-function(ind){
     for(i in 1:length(ind)){
         png(names(ind[i]), width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
         par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
         plot(x = c(1946, 2014),
               y = range(ind[[i]][,'VALUE']),
               type='b',
               main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],     
         dev.off() 
    }
}

elseFunction<-function(ind){
    for(i in 1:length(ind)){
        png(names(ind[i]), width=1679, height=1165, res=150)    
        par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
        plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
             type='b',
             main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
        dev.off()  
  }
}
```

And then call your ifelse

```
ifelse(xy$YEAR > 1946 & xy$YEAR < 2014, ifFunction(ind), elseFunction(ind))
```

Quick answer though, hopefully I didn't miss something!

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I'll create two plotting functions, one for each scenario (this is optional).

```
plot1 <- function(x) {
  fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(x = c(1946, 2014),
       y = range(x$VALUE),
       type='b',
       main=x[1, 'NAME'])     
  dev.off()
}

plot2 <- function(x) {
  fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
  png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)    
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(x[,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
    type='b',
    main=x[1, 'NAME'])
  dev.off() 
}
```

And then apply this function to each item in `ind`:

```
lapply(ind, function(x) ifelse(any(x$YEAR < 1946), plot2(x), plot1(x))
```